# Maintain previous page scroll position on browser back button on Next.js site

Tags: next.js

when  I navigate from page A to page B using Next.js `Link` tag and click browser back button, the page A is scrolled to the top. How can I preserve the scroll position of page A?

You can test this on my next.js blog.. scroll to bottom of [this page](https://gourav.io/blog) and click on an article link and hit browser back button, it gets scrolled to the top instead of preserving the scroll position.

source code: https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Personal-Site-Gourav.io

Answer (score 15, accepted):

fixed it by adding this flag to next.config.js

```js
experimental: {
      scrollRestoration: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing pagination and incorporate the Link component

```
import Link from 'next/link'
    
function PageLink({ pageNumber, currentPage }) {   
const isActive = pageNumber === currentPage   
const href = isActive ? null : `/blog?page=${pageNumber}`   

return (
        <Link href={href}>
          <a className={isActive ? 'active' : null}>{pageNumber}</a>
        </Link>   ) 
}
```

You can also define the total number of pages and return a specific page number using the router.

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
  const perPage = 10
  const totalPosts = posts.length
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalPosts / perPage)
  const router = useRouter()
  const currentPage = parseInt(router.query.page) || 1
  const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * perPage
  const endIndex = startIndex + perPage
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {currentPosts.map(post => (
        // render each post
      ))}
      <div className="pagination">
        {Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, i) => i + 1).map(pageNumber => (
          <PageLink key={pageNumber} pageNumber={pageNumber} currentPage={currentPage} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can add "prerender" to your meta tag to cache the content of the page and not fetch it again when the user returns to it.

```
<Head>
    <meta name="prerender-status-code" content="200" />
    <meta name="prerender" content="true" />
</Head>
```

Comment: not looking for a solution that includes paging

Comment: Use prerender to cache the content.